# Keyframes not visible with object selected

Tags: animation, keyframes

I know this gets asked frequently, but I'm stumped.

I keyframed a node property in an object material, saved and closed Blender, and then reopened it to find the keyframes missing from the timeline. However, the node property is still observed changing in the shader editor and the viewport.

This phenomenon occurs still after selecting the object and node in question, sequentially; and even if I disable "Only Keyframes from Selected Channels" in the view dropdown in the timeline window.

How do I return the keyframes to visibility in the timeline?

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx. or at least...provide a blend file with all relevant settings.

Comment: Make sure you don't have _Only Show Errors_ enabled in the _View_ menu of the _Timeline Editor_.

Comment: @moonboots Does the _Dope Sheet_ affect the visibility of keyframes in the _Timeline_?

Comment: oop no you're right, so I'm not sure what's happening to him, a blend file would be welcomed

Comment: @moonboots I suspect it's the _Only Show Errors_ option, we had this question here before but I didn't find it just yet. We have to wait for the OP to return to this question.

Comment: @moonboots I found the other question. I guess one of the answers there will provide the solution.

Comment: oh ok it might be that