# Keyframes Not Visible With Object Selected [2]

Tags: animation, keyframes

**Follow-up to [Keyframes not visible with object selected](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268386/keyframes-not-visible-with-object-selected)**

In short, keyframes disappeared from the timeline without losing effect, and previous solutions aren't restoring them to view.

I have attempted the following suggestions so far:

- Select object and node property sequentially
- Disable "Only Keyframes from Selected Channels" in Timeline Editor View menu
- Assure "Only Show Errors" is disabled
- Middle click and drag in the timeline to attempt to move keyframes in view
- Press the home key/click "Frame All" in the Timeline Editor

Unfortunately, none of these suggetions worked. I am providing my *.blend file.

[BLEND FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y7MUYy2PmbywLQNHrx2wqBeCfL07NfKb/view?usp=sharing)

The properties in question are color stop positions in the selected ColorRamp node in the object labeled "GHOST KEYFRAMES OBJECT".

Comment: there are no keyframes in your blend file....you can check yourself: insert a new and you will directly see it in the graph editor

Comment: @Chris You're right, there are none, that's the reason for the question - because the color ramp is still animated without keyframes, drivers etc.  ;)  I found the action anyway, I guess it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really providing an answer, since I guess this must be some kind of bug. The workaround depends on what you want to do: get completely rid of the animation or just change the animated values.

1. To get rid of the animation, simply duplicate the *Color Ramp* on a frame where you like the positions - the new ramp is without animation and uses the positions of the frame it was created. Of course you could (for simple things like this ramp) just add a new one.
2. To keep the animation, switch the *Outliner* window to *Display Mode* > *Data API*. IF you scroll down you'll find *Actions* where it says "2 items". These are two *Shader NodeTreeActions*, the second is orphaned data, the first is the one from the *Color Ramp*. If you open the hierarchy, there you will find the entries for the *F-Curves* where you can change the values. Of course it would still be easier to duplicate the *Color Ramp* and just add new keyframes, they will then show up in the *Timeline* and *Graph Editor*.

[image: data api]

3. Since *Data API* won't let you delete entries, another way to remove the action(s) could be to switch the *Outliner* to *Blender File*. There you will find them under *Action* (without the rest of the complete hierarchy like *F-Curves* etc.) and you can simply right-click on them and choose *Delete*.

[image: blender file]